# Looping in window.location

Tags: javascript, django, window.location

I am getting lat and lng from sessionStorage and I want to send it to browser  with window.location but i get to a infinity loop.

```
    var lat = sessionStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lng = sessionStorage.getItem('lng');       
    window.location = '?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng;
```

I saw other questions about this but they did not work.
I tryed to use window.location.hash / href etc... but the result is not what I expect

Does someone knows how to build that function to work properly?
Thank you very much

Comment: Why don't you add a `if` condition to check if the location url has already those parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a self invoked function to achieve what you want

```js
const redirect = (() => {
  var lat = sessionStorage.getItem("lat");
  var lng = sessionStorage.getItem("lng");
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  !params.get("lat") ? (window.location.href = `?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}`) : null;
})();
```

Comment: never understand why people use a ternary instead of an if. Makes code harder to read and does not save bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Check before setting the location so you are not stuck in the loop.

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const latQS = urlParams.get('lat');
const lat = sessionStorage.getItem('lat');
cost lng = sessionStorage.getItem('lng');       
if (!latQS && lat && lng) {
  const lat = sessionStorage.getItem('lat');
  cost lng = sessionStorage.getItem('lng');       
  window.location = '?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng;
}
```

Other option is setting the history with pushstate

```js
const lat = sessionStorage.getItem('lat');
cost lng = sessionStorage.getItem('lng');
if (lat && lng) { 
  const url = new URL(window.location);
  url.searchParams.set('lat', lat);
  url.searchParams.set('lng', lng);
  window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
}
```